# INSERT SQL statement inside a SELECT SQL statement in PostgreSQL

Tags: sql, postgresql

Can someone tell me why this doesn't work?

```
select * 
from keyword_groups_list 
where group_id = (insert into keyword_groups_list(group_name, keyword_tool_id) 
                  values('title', 86574551) returning group_id);
```

I get an error in PostgreSQL:

> ERROR: Syntax error at or near "into"
>   LINE 1: ...from keyword_groups_list where group_id = (insert into keywo...

Comment: What are you trying to achieve here?

Comment: you can't use an insert for returning a value to compare  .. explain better your goal  ..

Comment: first I am inserting a row in Postgres and after insertion, I am returning group_id of that inserted row. This group id will be used to insert into another table. But I am getting this error

Comment: Removed my comment @a_horse_with_no_name I was way off base on that one. Your CTE is beautiful, BTW and I'm totally going to steal that at some point in the future.

Answer (score 5):

I don't see why you would need the select at all. Just use `returning *` to get all columns of the newly inserted rows:

```
insert into keyword_groups_list(group_name, keyword_tool_id) 
values ('title', 86574551) 
returning *;
```

---

Having said that, you can however do this with a CTE, if you really need a select:

```
with new_groups as (
    insert into keyword_groups_list(group_name, keyword_tool_id) 
    values ('title', 86574551) 
    returning group_id
)
select * 
from keyword_groups_list 
where group_id in (select group_id from new_groups);
```

But I can't think of  any reason to prefer that over the simple `returning *`;

Comment: That INSERT CTE is a nice trick. I'm going to remember that one!

Comment: while running this sql statements, it returned empty row.

Answer (score 0):

You can access that value if you put it into a CTE

See this [SQL fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/b32d3/6)

```
with t as (
    insert into mytable (id, val) values(1,'abc') returning id
)
select * from anotherTable where id in (select id from t)
```

The [Postgres INSERT documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.5/static/sql-insert.html) has another CTE example like this too. Search for "Returning"

Or just simplify to

```
insert into mytable (id, val) values(1,'abc') returning *
```